# Element wise multiplication of a matrix and a vector?

Tags: vector, matrix, octave

Is there an in-built function in octave to multiply each column of a `m X n` element-wise with a column vector of size `m` that is more efficient than using a loop?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can replicate the vector as many times as you need to turn it into a `m x n` matrix as well and then use the built-in element-wise multiplication operator `.*`:

```
>> A = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6];
>> B = [1; 2; 3];

>> A .* repmat(B, 1, columns(A))
ans = 

    1    2
    6    8
   15   18
```

Comment: I believe that Octave will now do this automatically (they call it "broadcasting").  By default, you will get a warning.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried Anna Lear's answer but as nobar commented in that answer, Octave now does broadcasting. So you just have to do A.*B. You will get a warning that'll say an automatic product broadcasting is being applied

```
>> A.*B
warning: product: automatic broadcasting operation applied
ans =

 1    2
 6    8
15   18
```